Is it possible to cache uploaded image in browser?
I have an image-editor app, where I'm uploading an image and being redirected to another URL and downloading same image from server. Can I cache somewhere an image to skip the part, where I'm downloading an image, which I just uploaded? Saving a blob to localStorage is too tricky, because of few issues (size limit, string values only).

You can use the Cache API.
From MDN The Cache interface provides a persistent storage mechanism for Request / Response object pairs that are cached in long lived memory.
An example is linked in the documentation.
Custom Example (Comments are copies from the Cache API documentation refering to the API I am using.)
Upload and Cache
const file = // file object
const imageURL = // image url
const response = new Response(file)

// The open() method of the CacheStorage interface returns a Promise that resolves to the Cache object matching the cacheName.
caches.open('images').then(cache => {
    // Takes both a request and its response and adds it to the given cache.
    cache.put(imageURL, response);
});

Retrieve
caches.open('images').then(cache => {
    // The match() method of the CacheStorage interface checks if a given Request or URL string is a key for a stored Response.
    cache.match(imageURL).then(response => {
        if (response) {
            // Found
        } else {
            // Not found
        }
    });
});


I may have missed it, but I don't think that example shows how to cache local data. You'd have to build a Response from the Blob. So in the main doc you'd do   const store = await caches.open( "storename" ); await store.put(url, new Response(file)); and in the SW you'd use the code from the linked example.

@Kaiido you are kinda right. Thanks for the hint. The methods needed are in the example but it might be hard to adapt it. I added an example on the fly. If you find something to optimize feel free to add. I am on the go and have not much time :)

Oh, I didn't realise this is available outside of service workers as well!

<3 Yes :) "You don't have to use it in conjunction with service workers, even though it is defined in the service worker spec."

But here you are still fetching the resource first to get the Response, OP already has the data locally and will upload it to the server, so at that time they can't fetch it because it's not yet on the server, and once it is, it's just wasteing bandwidth to download again what they already have. So better build the response yourself with new Response(file) rather than fetching it.
